# WMI wql queries to fetch antivirus information

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, wql

What are the different sql queries which can help in fetching installed antivirus information ? 1 query i know which tells antivirus name ( as shown in the code below ).what are the other information which we can fetch using wql queries?

```
 string wmipathstr = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2";
 Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName );

 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");

 foreach (var instances in searcher.Get())
 {
   Console.WriteLine(instances.GetPropertyValue("displayName"));
 }
 Console.Read();
```

Comment: apart from "displayName" what else info we can fetch?

Comment: info like antivirus version or whether its firewall is turned on or off etc ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/05/12/how-to-get-antivirus-information-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx) shows a few more of the fields that should exist:

```
companyName
displayName
instanceGuid
onAccessScanningEnabled
pathToSignedProductExe
productHasNotifiedUser
productState
productUptoDate
productWantsWscNotifications
versionNumber
```

I'm guessing `productState` would be your 'whether it's on or off'.

Update: I believe you can use [`WscGetSecurityProviderHealth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432506) to get whether of not it's on instead, if that's all you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Guess what my main concern is about the firewall status only . Do you know how to use WscGetSecurityProviderHealth in c sharp.

Comment: Or if not can you please let me know how to use this product state method in c sharp . Any snippet if you could share .